# Move Top cut corner to bottom using linear-gradient

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Good morning,

I need assistance with the below attached image:

[Cut corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FHJ9.png)

Using linear gradient how do I move the top cut corner to the bottom corner and make the top corner square/sharp like the other corners. Please see current css below:

```
body.page {
  background: url(../img/Login-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  font-size: 14px;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.cut-corner {
  position: relative;
  color: #4a4a4c;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#bcd431, #bcd431), linear-gradient(#bcd431, #bcd431), linear-gradient(#bcd431, #bcd431), linear-gradient(#bcd431, #bcd431),
    linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent calc(50% - 0.5px), #bcd431 calc(50% - 0.5px), #bcd431 calc(50% + 0.5px), transparent calc(50% + 0.5px)), linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);
  background-size: 1.5px 100%, 1.5px 100%, 100% 1.5px, 100% 1.5px, 65px 65px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
  background-position: 0% 0%, 100% 65px, -65px 0%, 0px 100%, 100% 0%, -65px 0%, 100% 65px;
  margin: 25px;
}

.cut-corner:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#bcd431, #bcd431), linear-gradient(#bcd431, #bcd431), linear-gradient(#bcd431, #bcd431), linear-gradient(#bcd431, #bcd431),
    linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent calc(50% - 0.5px), #bcd431 calc(50% - 0.5px), #bcd431 calc(50% + 0.5px), transparent calc(50% + 0.5px)), linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);
  background-size: 0.5px 100%, 1.5px 100%, 100% 0.5px, 100% 1.5px, 65px 65px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
  background-position: 0% 0%, 100% 65px, -65px 0%, 0px 100%, 100% 0%, -65px 0%, 100% 65px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body class="page cut-corner">
...
</body>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You manage the cut in the `background-position` part like this

```
background-position: 0% 0%, 100% -65px, 0px 0%, -65px 100%, 100% 100%, -65px 50%, 100% 65px;
```

As you can see between each coma, there are two values defined of which the first one determines the position of each border (top border, bottom border...) and the other value defines the length of the border, try playing with the values and you will be able to make the top border full length, the bottom border a bit shorter, move the right border a bit higher and move the diagonal line to the bottom, then just change this from `bottom left` to `bottom right` as a way to change the angle of the small diagonal line like this

```
background-image: linear-gradient(#bcd431, #bcd431), linear-gradient(#bcd431, #bcd431), linear-gradient(#bcd431, #bcd431), linear-gradient(#bcd431, #bcd431),
linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent calc(50% - 0.5px), #bcd431 calc(50% - 0.5px), #bcd431 calc(50% + 0.5px), transparent calc(50% + 0.5px)), linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);
```

If you don't care about understanding it and just want to apply the code, here you go the entire code already modified (the only changes made are in `cut-corner:after`)

```
.cut-corner:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#bcd431, #bcd431), linear-gradient(#bcd431, #bcd431), linear-gradient(#bcd431, #bcd431), linear-gradient(#bcd431, #bcd431),
    linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent calc(50% - 0.5px), #bcd431 calc(50% - 0.5px), #bcd431 calc(50% + 0.5px), transparent calc(50% + 0.5px)), linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);
  background-size: 1px 100%, 1.5px 100%, 100% 1px, 100% 1.5px, 65px 65px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
  background-position: 0% 0%, 100% -65px, 0px 0%, -65px 100%, 100% 100%, -65px 50%, 100% 65px;
}
```

Comment: I am glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below, a combination of gradient and `clip-path` which is easier to handle

```css
.box {
  margin:10px;
  height:200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 50%,red 50.5%) 
    bottom right/50px 50px no-repeat;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% calc(100% - 50px),calc(100% - 50px) 100%, 0 100%); 
}

body {
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

With CSS variable to easily adjust the corner:

```css
.box {
  --c:50px;
  
  margin:10px;
  height:200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 50%,red 50.5%) 
    bottom right/var(--c) var(--c) no-repeat;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% calc(100% - var(--c)),calc(100% - var(--c)) 100%, 0 100%); 
}

body {
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="--c:100px;"></div>
```